# Applications of Complete Binary Tree?

Tags: data-structures, trees, binary-trees

Wondering what are the real word applications of the **Complete binary trees** or **Almost complete binary trees** where the the last level of the tree may not be complete and all nodes in the last level are aligned to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the [binairy heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) implementation of a priority queue.

The tree itself would be stored in an array, where access to children and parent is via computation of the position of the other nodes.